# How to install PHP pdo_pgsql driver version 13.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, php, postgresql

I have successfully installed some time ago a default installation of PHP 7.4 and of Postgresql v10 on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server.

Today I need to update my Postgresql version to 13.3 - but can't quite figure out how to get there.

- I have PHP v7.4.20 installed and running successfully
- Postgresql v13.3 is also installed and running successfully

```
    $ psql --version  
    psql (PostgreSQL) 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

- However PHPinfo lists the PDO_Pgsql driver version in use as v10
  [image: phpinfo]

***[Edit]*** The problem I'm facing occurs while trying to install an internally-developed application, during `composer install --no-dev` :
[image]

The app developer has validated the app for PGSQL v13.2+

=> How can I upgrade the version of PHP pdo_pgsql driver ?

Comment: Unless you are using some bleeding edge features, you shouldn't *need* to change your version of the `pdo_pgsql` driver. It will works with PostgreSQL versions 5.x ~ 12+ (I'm using this same version with a PostgreSQL 12.3 database, which I'll admit is not 13.x, but still). Are you seeing any particular errors when you try to connect or run queries?

Comment: @matigo I get an error in the postinstall phase of running `composer install`.
>In Exception.php line 18: could not find driver
>In PDOConnection.php line 38: could not find driver
>Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
While checking some more , we have a line in `doctrine.yaml` setting
`server_version: 13.3`
This was added by the developer to fix some issues, but not sure what exactly.

Comment: Actually it looks like my problem lies not with the PHP driver, but with the PSQL installation itself... My Psql *client* is v13.3 but a `show server_version` shows that the *server* version is the old v10...  I'll look into that!!

Comment: Running around in circles... I've gotten the server_version up to `13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg18.04+1)`. However PHP PDO_pgsql still uses v10.17 according to phpinfo.  @matigo - I've added the message from the initial error, which leads me to this PDO driver (could be wrong of course). If you have any suggestions... ?